# Keep the clicked objects in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I made a puzzle game in javascript. I have made objects to keep some attributes relevant to the each pazzle squares. I want to get the object id which is relevant to the onclick.(not the div id). How to get the specific object id relevant to the clicked div?

```
window.onload = function() {
    createDivs();
    objects();
    random();
    onclickeventHanlder(event);
};


var getId;
var x = 3;
var counting = 0;
var tileSize = 600 / x;
var array2 = [];
var object = [];


function createDivs() {

    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            var id = i + "" + j;

            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.setAttribute("class", "pieces");
            element.setAttribute("id", id);
            element.style.width = 600 / x + "px";
            element.style.height = 600 / x + "px";
            element.style.margin = "0px auto";
            element.style.overflow = "hidden";
            element.setAttribute("onclick", "onclickeventHanlder(this)");

            if (count > 0) {  // to break row-wise
                if (i == count && j == 0) {
                    element.style.clear = "both";
                }
            }
            element.style.float = "left";
            document.getElementById('puzzle-body').appendChild(element);  
        }
        count++;
    }
}


function  objects(){
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {

        var objName = new Object();
        objName.position = -(j * tileSize) + "px" + " " + -(i * tileSize) + "px";
        objName.divID = document.getElementById(i + "" + j);
        objName.id = count;
        if(count<x*x-1){
        objName.state = true; // if image is there
        }else{
        objName.state = false; // if image isn't there  
        }
    object[count] = objName;
    count++;
    }
}
}


function reset(){
    var looping = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {

        var obj  = object[looping];

        if(obj.id<8){
        var urlString = 'url("../images/Golden.jpg")';
        obj.divID.style.backgroundImage = urlString;
        obj.divID.style.backgroundPosition = obj.position; 
            }
            looping++;
        }
    }

}


function random(){

   var array = [];

       while (array.length < ((x * x) - 1)) {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((x * x) - 1));
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == randomnumber) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            array[array.length] = randomnumber;
        }
    }


        var looping = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            if (looping < x * x-1) {
                var random = array[looping];

                var obj = object[random];
                var obj2 = object[looping];

                        if(obj.id<8){
              var urlString = 'url("../images/Golden.jpg")';
              obj.divID.style.backgroundImage = urlString;
              obj.divID.style.backgroundPosition = obj2.position; 
            }
            }
            looping++;
        }


}

}

function onclickeventHanlder(event) {
var pos = event;
}
```

Comment: to make the relation between your div and object id, i think you have used variable count. but in your createDivs function, you have incremented count inside first for loop and in your objects() function you have incremented count inside second for loop. To fix this, move count++ from first loop to second for loop in createDivs function.

Comment: Then how i identify the relevant object in onclick() event fires.

Comment: you can pass count as a param in onclickeventHanlder. and then inside onclickeventHanlder function you can get object id as  object[count].id or also do note that your object id is same as count : objName.id = count;

Comment: Actually the count variable is defined to push the  objects into array and giving ids for objects. I want to keep an array for onclickeventHandler. If you can please support me to implement this.

Comment: What is the game supposed to do @PriyanthaWeerasinghe

Comment: This is an image puzzle. This puzzle has 3*3 grid. But it's last square is blank. When i click the each and every square it should have to search about the blank square where is near to that clicked square. I have kept this attribute in a object as object.state = false for blank square.